# How do you center parbox vertically in a table

Tags: tables, parbox

I created a table with images in them.
However I want the first column to have text and it should be centered vertically and the text should be rotated 90degrees.
To do this, I used a parbox however I cannot seem to vertically center it.
Does anybody know what I can do?

```
\begin{table*}[h!]
     \begin{center}
        %  \begin{tabular}{ p{1cm}  p{5cm}  p{5cm}  p{5cm}}
         \begin{tabular}{c c c c}
             \toprule
              Planner & Full Communication & Partial Communication & Poor Communication \\ 
              \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3}\cmidrule(l){4-4} % the bar under the col title
              {\centering
              \parbox[t]{4mm}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{MCTS (Greedy) CNN}}
              }
              & 
             \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=50mm]{images/sample.png}}
              & 
              \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=50mm]{images/sample.png}}
              &
             \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=50mm]{images/sample.png}}
              \\
             \bottomrule
             
              A             
              & 
             \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=50mm]{images/sample.png}}
              & 
              \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=50mm]{images/sample.png}}
              &
             \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=50mm]{images/sample.png}}
              \\
             \bottomrule
             
              A             
              & 
             \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=50mm]{images/sample.png}}
              & 
              \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=50mm]{images/sample.png}}
              &
             \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=50mm]{images/sample.png}}
              \\
             \bottomrule
             
              A             
              & 
             \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=50mm]{images/sample.png}}
              & 
              \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=50mm]{images/sample.png}}
              &
             \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=50mm]{images/sample.png}}
              \\
             \bottomrule
             
          \end{tabular}
          \caption{my.Lboro Analysis}
          \label{tbl:myLboro}
      \end{center}
  \end{table*}
```

[image: What this code produces]

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please always provide a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) to make things easier for people willing to help and test your code. Thank you.

Comment: It would be nice to have a full example we can compile ourselves, but my initial suggestion is to get rid of all the `\raisebox`es and change the colspec from `\begin{tabular}{c c c c}` to `\begin{tabular}{c m{0.3\textwidth} m{0.3\textwidth} m{0.3\textwidth}}`. (Requires the array package.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

- we haven't any information used documentclass and about your document layout, so please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small complete document, which contain now mised information
- it is not clear desired table layout )are all cells in the first column have rotated text or as it follows from your code fragment
- by use of `adjustbox`, `rotating`, `makecell`  and `tabularray` packages which enables to write concise and clear table code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{MCTS (Greedy)}
    \adjustboxset{width=\linewidth, height=33mm,
                  valign=M}
\begin{tblr}{colsep = 3pt,
             colspec = {@{} Q[c] X[c] X[c] X[c] @{}},
             rowsep = 3pt,
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries, c, m},
            }
     \toprule
Planner 
    & Full Communication 
        & Partial Communication 
            & Poor Communication                        \\
    \cmidrule[r]{1-1}
    \cmidrule[lr]{2-2}\cmidrule[l]{3-3}\cmidrule[l]{4-4} 
\SetCell{cmd=\rotcell[cc]}   {MCTS (Greedy)\\ CNN} 
    &   \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}
        &   \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}
            &   \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}    \\
    \midrule
A
    &   \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}
        &   \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}
            &   \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}    \\
    \midrule
B
    &   \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}
        &   \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}
            &   \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}    \\

    \midrule
C
    &   \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}
        &   \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}
            &   \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\caption{my.Lboro Analysis}
\label{tbl:myLboro}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
You may liked a bit different column headers, in which are not repeated column content informations:

[image]

For this the following changes in above MWE are needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{MCTS (Greedy)}
    \adjustboxset{width=\linewidth, height=33mm,
                  valign=M}
\begin{tblr}{colsep = 3pt,
             colspec = {@{} Q[c,h] X[c] X[c] X[c] @{}},
             rowsep = 3pt,
             row{1,2} = {font=\bfseries, c, m},
            }
     \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{c}   Planner 
    & \SetCell[c=3]{c}Communication 
        &   &                                               \\
    \midrule
    & Full 
        & Partial 
            & Poor                                          \\
    \midrule
\SetCell{cmd=\rotcell[cc]}   {MCTS (Greedy)\\ CNN} 
    &   \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}
        &   \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}
            &   \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}    \\
    \midrule
% rest of table code
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses the [valign=...] feature of adjustbos/graphicx.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[tp]% table* does not support [h]
     \centering
     %\setkeys{Gin}{valaign=M}% doesn't work
        %  \begin{tabular}{ p{1cm}  p{5cm}  p{5cm}  p{5cm}}
         \begin{tabular}{c c c c}
             \toprule
              Planner & Full Communication & Partial Communication & Poor Communication \\ 
              \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3}\cmidrule(l){4-4} % the bar under the col title
              \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{MCTS (Greedy) CNN}
              & 
             \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=50mm, valign=M]{example-image}
              & 
             \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=50mm, valign=M]{example-image}
              &
             \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=50mm, valign=M]{example-image}\llap{\rule{5cm}{0.5pt}}
              \\
             \bottomrule
             
              A             
              & 
             \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=50mm, valign=t]{example-image}
              & 
             \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=50mm, valign=t]{example-image}
              &
             \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=50mm, valign=t]{example-image}
              \\
             \bottomrule
             
              A             
              & 
             \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=50mm, valign=t]{example-image}
              & 
             \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=50mm, valign=t]{example-image}
              &
             \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=50mm, valign=t]{example-image}
              \\
             \bottomrule
             
              A             
              &
             \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=50mm, valign=t]{example-image}
              & 
             \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=50mm, valign=t]{example-image}
              &
             \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=50mm, valign=t]{example-image}
              \\
             \bottomrule
             
          \end{tabular}
          \caption{my.Lboro Analysis}
          \label{tbl:myLboro}
  \end{table*}
  
  \end{document}
```