# How can I create an extra row in the table given here?

Tags: tables

I want to add an extra row so that the images in the columns after the first can be separated into two more columns as shown in the second image I uploaded. The "1" and "2" drawn in red represents the columns I want to add.

I tried playing around with the code but was not successful.
Could anyone help me out?

[image: How the table looks currently]

[image: How the table SHOULD look like]

This is the code to create the table:

```
\begin{table*}[t]
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{MCTS (Greedy)}
    \adjustboxset{width=36mm, height=36mm,
                  valign=M}
\begin{tblr}{colsep = 3pt,
             colspec = {@{} Q[c,h] X[c] X[c] @{}},
             rowsep = 3pt,
             row{1,2} = {font=\bfseries, c, m},
            }
     \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{c}   Ground Truth 
    & \SetCell[c=3]{c}Communication 
        &   &                                               \\
    \midrule
    & Full 
            & Poor                                          \\
    \midrule
    \adjincludegraphics[width=1.35in]{images/circ_gt.png} 
            &   \adjincludegraphics[width=1.35in]{images/circ_full_ourmethod_74} \adjincludegraphics[width=1.35in]{images/circ_full_othermethod_54}
            % &   \adjincludegraphics{images/circ_partial_55}
                &   \adjincludegraphics[width=1.35in]{images/circ_poor_ourmethod_60} 
                \adjincludegraphics[width=1.35in]{images/circ_poor_othermethod_47} \\
    \midrule
      \adjincludegraphics[width=1.35in]{images/depoe_gt.png}
        &   \adjincludegraphics[width=1.35in]{images/depoe_full_ourmethod_269}
        \adjincludegraphics[width=1.35in]{images/depoe_full_othermethod_190}
            % &   \adjincludegraphics{images/depoe_partial_246}
                &   \adjincludegraphics[width=1.35in]{images/depoe_poor_ourmethod_261}
                \adjincludegraphics[width=1.35in]{images/depoe_poor_othermethod_136}   \\
    \end{tblr}
\caption{my.Lboro Analysis}
\label{tbl:myLboro}
    \end{table*}
```

These are the packages/settings I use in the root file:

```
\documentclass[lettersize,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
% \usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor IEEE-Xplore}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\usepackage{balance}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

% package to color comments for multiple users
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\gb}[1]{{\color{RawSienna}\textit{(GB) #1}}}
\newcommand{\ks}[1]{{\color{blue}\textit{(KS) #1}}}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

% \usepackage{caption} 
% \captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}

\usepackage{algorithm, algorithmicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
% \usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}

%%%%%%% Vertical Lines in Algos %%%%%%% 
\errorcontextlines\maxdimen

% begin vertical rule patch for algorithmicx (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144840/vertical-loop-block-lines-in-algorithmicx-with-noend-option)
% note that some of the packages above are also needed
\newcommand{\ALGtikzmarkcolor}{black}% customise this, if you want
\newcommand{\ALGtikzmarkextraindent}{4pt}% customise this, if you want
\newcommand{\ALGtikzmarkverticaloffsetstart}{-.5ex}% customise this, if you want
\newcommand{\ALGtikzmarkverticaloffsetend}{-.5ex}% customise this, if you want
\makeatletter
\newcounter{ALG@tikzmark@tempcnta}

\newcommand\ALG@tikzmark@start{%
    \global\let\ALG@tikzmark@last\ALG@tikzmark@starttext%
    \expandafter\edef\csname ALG@tikzmark@\theALG@nested\endcsname{\theALG@tikzmark@tempcnta}%
    \tikzmark{ALG@tikzmark@start@\csname ALG@tikzmark@\theALG@nested\endcsname}%
    \addtocounter{ALG@tikzmark@tempcnta}{1}%
}

\def\ALG@tikzmark@starttext{start}
\newcommand\ALG@tikzmark@end{%
    \ifx\ALG@tikzmark@last\ALG@tikzmark@starttext
        % ignore this, the block was opened then closed directly without any other blocks in between (so just a \State basically)
        % don't draw a vertical line here
    \else
        \tikzmark{ALG@tikzmark@end@\csname ALG@tikzmark@\theALG@nested\endcsname}%
        \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \draw[\ALGtikzmarkcolor] let \p{S}=($(pic cs:ALG@tikzmark@start@\csname ALG@tikzmark@\theALG@nested\endcsname)+(\ALGtikzmarkextraindent,\ALGtikzmarkverticaloffsetstart)$), \p{E}=($(pic cs:ALG@tikzmark@end@\csname ALG@tikzmark@\theALG@nested\endcsname)+(\ALGtikzmarkextraindent,\ALGtikzmarkverticaloffsetend)$) in (\x{S},\y{S})--(\x{S},\y{E});%
    \fi
    \gdef\ALG@tikzmark@last{end}%
}



% the following line injects our new tikzmarking code
\apptocmd{\ALG@beginblock}{\ALG@tikzmark@start}{}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}
\pretocmd{\ALG@endblock}{\ALG@tikzmark@end}{}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}
\makeatother
% end vertical rule patch for algorithmicx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Please, be so king and always provide an MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document, which reproduce your problem.
- In the your case that means, that you should merge both code fragments and from them remove all definitions and loading packages which are not related to your problem.
- It is not entirely clear, what is your problem. If you need one more row, just insert it where is needed, but as I see, your table code has other issues too.
- Showed images are not produced by providing code fragments.
- How many images you have in row?
- BTW, if you for code fragment for your table with images use code from my solution for your ([previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649382/how-do-you-center-parbox-vertically-in-a-table)), it would be nice to accept it first ...

An example of MWE, which (hopefully) solve problem, can be:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[export, 
            demo            % in real document remove this option
            ]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
%\begin{figure*}
    \adjustboxset{width=\linewidth, height=36mm,        % <---
                  valign=M}
\begin{tblr}{colsep = 3pt,
             colspec = {@{} *{5}{X[c]} @{}},            % <---
             rowsep = 3pt,
             row{1,2} = {font=\bfseries, c, m},
            }
     \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{c}   Ground Truth
    &   \SetCell[c=4]{c}    Communication               % <---
        &   &   &                                       \\
    \midrule
    &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Full                        % <---
        &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Poor                % <---
                &                                       \\
    \cmidrule[r]{2-3}
    \cmidrule[r]{4-5}
    & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2                                     \\  % <--- new row
    \midrule                                            % <---
\adjincludegraphics{images/circ_gt.png}
    &   \adjincludegraphics{images/circ_full_ourmethod_74}    
        &   \adjincludegraphics{images/circ_full_othermethod_54}
%            &   \adjincludegraphics{images/circ_partial_55} 5 <--- ??? are you have 6 images in row?
                &   \adjincludegraphics{images/circ_poor_ourmethod_60}
                    &   \adjincludegraphics{images/circ_poor_othermethod_47} \\
    \midrule
\adjincludegraphics{images/depoe_gt.png}
    &   \adjincludegraphics{images/depoe_full_ourmethod_269}
        &   \adjincludegraphics{images/depoe_full_othermethod_190}
%            &   \adjincludegraphics{images/depoe_partial_246}
            &   \adjincludegraphics{images/depoe_poor_ourmethod_261}
                &   \adjincludegraphics{images/depoe_poor_othermethod_136}   \\
    \end{tblr}
\caption{my.Lboro Analysis}
\label{tbl:myLboro}
%    \end{figure*}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

In code are marked by `% <---` code lines where are done changes in your table code.  Regardin it, some comments:

- in table always define so many columns as you than use them
- columns must be always separated by `&` (ampersands), at `tabularray` package   regardless if in some row are some cells merged to multicolumn cell (in contrary to " classic tables, where this is not required)

[image]

(red lines indicate text area borders)

Result in the case when instead of `table*` is used `figure*`:

[image]
Is this what you after?

Comment: sorry about not accepting your previous answer before posting a new question.
Also I will be sure to post a MWE next time.
This is exactly what i'm looking and thank you very much for taking time out of your day for the detailed answer.

Comment: would you know how to wrap this table in a figure? I tried however it does not seem to appear in the document when I compile. I also tried figure* but it did not work.

Comment: @Kavi, if I correctly understood your comment, you only need to replace `table*` with ˙`figure*`.  This should work (tested). However, now I see, that I forgot to delete not used packages as well as not used `\rotheadsize`. Corrected now.

Comment: This worked! I was trying to wrap it but just changing table to figure worked. Thank you!

Comment: The tbale is working however, there are quite a few errors appearing like "Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `r'." at \end{tblr} which I think has nothing do with xcolor. The other errors include "Missing number, treated as zero." (multiple) and "Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)". Are you getting these errors as well?

Comment: @Kavi, my MWE in answer work as it is. Writing it I assume, that table is "black/white", i.e.  not content any color. If you want to have colors, than please load `xcolor` (with desired options) before `tabularray` package. MWE is tested by `tabularray` package version2022C. Which version of package you use?